# Error building archive in xcode for flutter.io app

Tags: flutter

I follow release instructions but I am getting a link error building the archive about the Reachability library not being found:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/bartwaggoner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-duuffrseacvinacmifrehqvwbbxo/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Reachability'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/bartwaggoner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-duuffrseacvinacmifrehqvwbbxo/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/connectivity'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/bartwaggoner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-duuffrseacvinacmifrehqvwbbxo/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/path_provider'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/bartwaggoner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-duuffrseacvinacmifrehqvwbbxo/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher'
ld: library not found for -lReachability
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've played around for half a day and so far no luck resolving this - could anyone help a mac.flutter newbie out?

Comment: I notice in my xcode project that the "Pods" folder is empty, unllike the "Flutter", "Runner" etc. folders. Is this the problem? In my Intellij project the ios/Pods folder is not empty and has Reachability etc. in it.  If this is not getting exporte to the xcode project how do I change this?

Comment: OK fixed that error - I was opening .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace. Now I get build error (link error) unless I target iOS 11 - targeting iOS 10 or older gives following errors:  "OBJC_CLASS$_FlutterError", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in liburl_launcher.a(UrlLauncherPlugin.o)
"_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
-[ConnectivityPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in libconnectivity.a(ConnectivityPlugin.o)
___47+[FLTPathProviderPlugin registerWithRegistrar:]_block_invoke in libpath_provider.a(PathProviderPlugin.o)...

Answer (score 2):

Opening the `.xcodeproj` extension file instead of the `.xcworkspace` worked for me.